# Libreoffice Writer - Can we have sections which don't move?

Tags: libreoffice

I am using the latest Libreoffice Writer. I have a few chapters in my work, which begin on new pages. When I make a change, for example, to Chapter 1, I don't want the beginning of Chapter 2 to move up or down from the beginning of the new page it is already on. I tried using sections, but they move too. I am sure there is an obvious answer to this, but I couldn't find it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described into [official documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Inserting_and_Deleting_Page_Breaks) of Libreoffice Writer:

- To insert a page break: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>,
- To delete a page break: <kbd>Backspace</kbd> having focus in front of first character of the next page.

Comment: thank you very much, I was not aware before that the term for this is a 'page break'